# Can I delete the System partition after converting from MBR to GPT?

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I just converted my Windows system disk from MBR to GPT.

Windows now has this tool, which failed to validate for me, saying it couldn't find my OS:

[MBR2GPT.exe | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt)

So instead, I used MiniTool Partition Wizard to convert from MBR to GPT:

[How to Convert MBR Disk to GPT | MiniTool Partition Wizard Tutorial](https://www.partitionwizard.com/help/convert-MBR-disk-to-GPT-disk.html)

My final disk layout has 3 partitions:

```
[System][Windows...][EFI]
```

Can I delete the old `[System]` partition at this point?

It would be nice to remove it from the Clover bootloader screen, and the extra 350MB of space would be a bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short Answer

**No.** Regardless of partition structure, you cannot delete the System Reserved partition.

### Long Answer

Unless you plan on using BitLocker (or any system-modifying programs), you **can delete it**, but caution is advised. If you encounter any boot problems, you will have to use an external repair disk. (Again, regardless of partition structure.)

### Sources

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-system-reserved-partition-windows-1087-abdul-salam

Answer (score -1):

You'd better not delete this partition, because it stores files used for bitlocker drive encryption. For more details, please see https://www.howtogeek.com/192772/what-is-the-system-reserved-partition-and-can-you-delete-it/

Comment: Link-only answers are not typically considered helpful.  You should edit this answer so it includes all relevant information to answer the question